# SQL Adding default values where not in source table to a GROUP BY result set

Tags: sql-server-2008, group-by, resultset, default-value

I have a table called student:

Student [UPN, ks2en, ks2ma, ks2ma]

This is joined to a table called subject:

Subject [UPN, Result]

I have used a case statement to specify which column of Student to use in the resultset. This is my case statement:

```
    GROUP BY
       CASE Name
            WHEN 'English' THEN
                CASE WHEN [Ks2en] IS NULL OR [Ks2en]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2en] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                WHEN [Ks2en] IN ('2a','2b','2c') THEN 
                    '2'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2en]
                END
            WHEN 'Mathematics' THEN
                CASE WHEN [Ks2ma] IS NULL OR [Ks2ma]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2ma] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                WHEN [Ks2ma] IN ('2a','2b','2c') THEN 
                    '2'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2ma]
                END
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN [Ks2av] IS NULL OR [Ks2av]='' THEN
                    'No KS2'
                WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('1a','1b','1c') THEN 
                    '1'
                WHEN [Ks2av] IN ('2a','2b','2c') THEN 
                    '2'
                ELSE
                    [Ks2av]
                END
            END
```

The result set also includes count functions depending on the subject result, but this isn't important for my question.

What I would like to do is force the resultset to include a specific set of values whether these exist in the original column or not.

For example the subject is English and therefore the resultset uses the student column ks2en, but this only contains the following values:

```
4a, 4a, 3b, 3c, 5a. The resultset when using a GROUP BY gives:

4a
3b
3c
5a
```

But I would like the GROUP BY to by default contain the following at the very least, but with NULLs in the counts and figures where there are values.

```
1, 2, 3c, 3b, 3a, 4c, 4b, 4a, 5c, 5b, 5a, 6c, 6b, 6a
```

Answer (score 0):

The general construct would be:

```
;WITH fixed_values AS 
(
  SELECT x FROM (VALUES('1'),('2'),('3c'), ...) AS x(x)
)
SELECT x FROM fixed_values
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
  -- your grouped query
) AS q
ON fixed_values.x = q.kswhatever
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm struggling to implement it. Should I be wrapping my entire query with this or purely the GROUP BY?